# calling a member function of different class from another class

Tags: c++, function

I have two classes A and B. The control is inside one of the member functions of class A. The member function calculates a result and i now want to send this value to one of the member functions of class B, I tried the following way, yet it dint work

```
int memberFunctionOfA()
{
... //results are stored in some temporary value, say temp

B::memberFunctionOfB(temp);  // the way i tried
}
```

The comiler reported an error. I also tried like

```
B obj;
obj.memberFunctionOfB(temp);
```

Both gave me errors that the memberFunctionOfB cannot be called. Can anyone tell me what am i missing

**Edit**

Class B is not inherited from A. They both are independent. Both the member functions are public and non static

Comment: Tell us the exact error that the compiler shows.

Comment: @CHID I don't understand memberFunctionOfB is static function?

Comment: The declaration of class B would help a lot here.  If A inherits from B (or the other way around), class A's declaration would help as well.  First guess, i'd say `memberFunctionOfB` is private/protected, but it's hard to say for sure without seeing the code.

Comment: The compiler throws "No matching funtion call B::B()"

Comment: @CHID: That particular error means your class B doesn't have a default constructor.  IF you want to create a B, you'll need to supply arguments -- like `B obj(42, "These are sample args");` rather than just `B obj;`.  Look through the code for class B and find out what its constructor expects.

Comment: compiler said your class B doesn't have default constructor which is required to create object on the stack like you do here: `B obj;`

Comment: @all: thank you for spotting the error

Answer (score 3):

Your second attempt:

```
int memberFunctionOfA()
{
... //results are stored in some temporary value, say temp

    B obj;
    obj.memberFunctionOfB(temp);
}
```

..., looks perfectly valid. We will need the definition of B to help further. B's definition should minimally have, assuming that the member function in B is non-static:

```
class B
{
public:
  void memberFunctionOfB(const TypeOfTemp &temp);
};

// Later in class A's definition
class A
{
public:
  int memberFunctionOfA()
  {
    ... //results are stored in some temporary value, say temp

    B b;
    b.memberFunctionOfB(temp);
  }
};
```

If the member function in B is static, then this should work:

```
class B
{
public:
  static void memberFunctionOfB(const TypeOfTemp &temp);
};

...

class A
{
public:
  int memberFunctionOfA()
  {
    ... //results are stored in some temporary value, say temp

    B::memberFunctionOfB(temp);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

After seeing your comment:

> The compiler throws "No matching function call B::B()"

That means, there is no default constructor for class `B`. In your implementation, B`s constructor must be taking parameter.

So either you add a default constructor to your class, or you pass the argument to your constructor when creating an instance of it.

Comment: Thank you nawaz. As they pointed out, i missed the default constructor.